# Why does media-body class in bootstrap have width 10,000px and media class have overflow hidden and zoom 1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some question regarding the media classes in bootstrap.

1. Why does `.media-body` class in bootstrap have width 10,000px? Why did they use `display: table-cell` not `display: block`?
2. Why is `overflow: hidden` and `zoom: 1`used on `.media` class?
3. Why doesn't the div with `.media-body` actually take 10,000px width?
4. What would happen if `overflow: hidden` and `zoom: 1` are not used in `.media` class?

As for my effort, I removed `overflow, zoom` and `10,000px` width and observed no difference.

Answer (score 3):

I have found some comments in the collection "[Responsive Bootstrap](https://github.com/tedw/responsive-bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_helpers.scss)":

```
/*
 * 1. Create new block formatting context in modern browsers
 * 2. Avoid shrink-wrap behaviour of table-cell
 * 3. Override for IE6/7
 * 4. Create new block formatting context in IE6/7
 * Alternatively, use 'overflow:hidden' if clipping is OK
*/
display: table-cell; /* 1 */
width: 10000px; /* 2 */
@include old-ie() {
    *width: auto; /* 3 */
    *zoom: 1; /* 4 */
}
```

**UPD**

`*zoom` is a hack for IE6 and IE7. All browsers ignore attributes that begin with an asterisk. Only IE7 and below takes them into account.

Comment: Could you give some explanation for these points? Like what is _shrink-wrap_ behaviour? What is the difference between `*zoom` and `zoom`?

Comment: @user31782 `*zoom` is a hack for IE6 and IE7. All browsers ignore attributes that begin with an asterisk. Only IE7 and below takes them into account.

Comment: But in my `bootstrap.css` they are not using `*zoom` in `.media` class. It is line 5207 of the source file. They have written `.media-body {
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}`